# Create Test Plan in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online.

I want to create a test plan. As per the Microsoft tutorial, It should be created by clicking on the "+" sign as shown in the picture below.

[image]

**more info: I am following this link**

```
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/create-a-test-plan-vs
```

But I could not see any option to create the test plan (see picture below).

[image]

Please provide the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that second screenshot from your VSOnline account, if so, I can see the + button there in the top left.

Comment: It is just a picture in my second screenshot.. it is not the actual "+" option. It's a demo screen only(It should be like the first screenshot).

Comment: Do you have a Premium or above MSDN license?

Comment: Andrew, I found that I need to configure my account for MSDN license. Only account owner is not enough..After doing so, I am able to see the expected screen. Thanks for the help..

Comment: @Shaishav7 so how did you finally manage to solve this problem as I'm stuck on this same one. Did you buy any subscription for this?

Answer (score 5):

The ability to create test plans only comes with certain Visual Studio Online licenses. Here is your reference guide:
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-overview-vs#AdditionalPageSections_1

Comment: +1, I've also replicated this. I don't really understand it though, since a Basic user can create Test Cases and run Test Plans. They just need an MSDN user to create the Test Plans and add the Test Cases to them... Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: FWIW, they've changed the pricing model and license capabilities for these features since my original answer. Many of the test features have moved to the [Test Manager extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms.vss-testmanager-web). I believe the reason they charge to create test plans is because they consider it to be 'Test Planning', which is a role which is specific to a particular VSTS user type

Comment: @Josh does this mean that we need to buy the Test Manager Extension for documenting Test Plans and Test Cases?

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Test Plan" option in that drop down menu in your top screenshot. That should allow you to create a new test plan.

Comment: Andrew, problem is that i could not see that option on my screen. I see the screen like the second screenshot..